# URI and URL for CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having a problem understanding the docs on the CodeIgniter website dealing with URI segments and URLs combined.

Lets say I have a site `www.whatever.com/`

And on my main page I have a link that when clicked on will go to `www.whatever.com/news/test-story`

Question is do I make a new controller just for the news or how is this link about to be gone to correctly?

Comment: CodeIgniter URLs are `http://WebSite.com/<Controller>/<Function>/<Param1>/<Param2>`.  So, in your URL, `news` would be the controller, and `test-story` would be the function inside the controller that's called.

Comment: So your saying every page of mine is going to have its own controller

Comment: Is that how I should be doing it?

Comment: If you want to organize it that way.  You can have them all be in the same controller if you want, up to you.  You should have separate controllers for each thing.  For example, you can have a `news` controller that handles articles, a `users` controller that handles user logins, and maybe a `comments` controller.

Comment: which do you suggest because you seem to know what you're talking about with the last couple of questions I"ve had.

Comment: I use CodeIgniter at my job, so I know what I'm doing (possibly :-P).  Anyway, how my blog does it is, I have multiple controllers.  `article`, `comments` and `users`.  So that way I have urls like `/article/view/12`, `/users/profile/Rocket`, and `/comments/add/34`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5069/discussion-between-jeff-davidson-and-rocket)

Answer (score 3):

Using your example, `whatever.com/news/story` would map to a function called `story` in a controller called `news`:

```
class News extends CI_Controller {

    function story() {
        // get a news story
    }
}
```

Of course, CodeIgniter provides [URI Routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) in which you can "remap" URLs to other controllers and functions.

Comment: I made that however its saying that the page can not be found.

Comment: There's also the [`_remap()`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping) function.

Comment: Depending on your `.htaccess` file, you may need `index.php` in there like whatever.com/index.php/news/story

Comment: what if I took it out meaning didn't want the index.php showing up

Comment: @Jeff: If you used a `.htaccess` file to remove `index.php` from your URLs and have no custom routing added, then that URL *should* work. You can't just not include `index.php` without doing some extra work.

Comment: can I get someone come into the chat above

Comment: Just to cover all of the bases: that URL can also map to the `index()` function of a controller name `story` that is in a folder named "news" in the controller folder.